Divider shifting upwards when browser window is getting resize

I've created a divider in accordance with the design provided in figma. This divider is positioned below the tabs and placed within a workspace bottom container. It looks visually appealing and complements the active tabs design that I've implemented. However, when resizing the browser screen upwards, the position of the divider shifts unexpectedly.
below is the css code of my divider:-

<>
 <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}> 
    <div
        style={{
            width: "32%",
            top: "30%",
            position: "absolute",
            left: "320px",
            borderBottom: "1px solid #DBDBDB",
            overflow: "hidden",
        }}
    ></div>
</div>
<>

Here is the image of my divider when it is getting resized:-
enter image description here

Your divider has absolute positioning, meaning it is removed from normal document flow. It wants to position itself relative to its closest ancestor with the position attribute set on it, and if it finds none, it will position itself relative to the initial containing block (that is, the <html> element).
In essence, your divider has no idea it's supposed to be positioned relative to your tabs because you've told it to ignore normal document flow.
